# MVC normal html form binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've seen thousands of examples using the razor BeginForm and I know that it auto binds the controller input to the submitted info... anyway I want to know if the same auto bind exists in a normal

`<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
      <input type="text" name="foo">
 </form>`
and if it doesn't ... how can I bind it... and please don't tell me to use html helpers...

Comment: If you want to set value for _foo_ input you can use this: `<input type="text" name="foo" value="@Model.foo">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can `bind model` with normal html but the value of the name `attribute` has to be same as name of the `property` of the `model` e.g

```
public class viewmodel
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string  LastName {get; set;}  
}
```

so your `html` will be

```
@model viewmodel

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="@model.FirstName"> //name should be of same name as property name
      <input type="text" name="LastName" value="@model.LastName">
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

and finally your `action` will be

```
public ActionResult Index(viewmodel model)
{
   return View(model);
}
```